# issues migrating ionic 1 code to ionic 4/5

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I am migrating ionic 1 code to ionic 5. I do not have much experience with ionic 1. So some code is bit confusing. I would like to know what is equivalent of following code in ionic 4/5.

```
    $ionicHistory.clearCache();
    $ionicHistory.clearHistory();
    $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
      disableAnimate: true,
      disableBack: true
    });
```

If someone knows then please let me know. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done like this:

```
import {Router, NavigationExtras } from ‘@angular/router’;

let navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
skipLocationChange: true,
replaceUrl: true
};

//Where home is the page where app will navigate
this.router.navigate([’/home’], navigationExtras);
```